# How to replace and write multiple strings into a file?

Tags: python

I'm copying data from an original to a new file, and randomly assigning new values to the strings that I'd like to change. For some reason, the code I have will only replace one of my strings. I've tried writing four different filedata.replace lines corresponding to four f.write commands, but that won't work. I've also tried to give filedata.replace multiple arguments in one command, but that creates problems as well.

```
import numpy as np
import random
import math
import shutil

for i in range (1,5):
    shutil.copy('template.par', 'a.par')

    a = str(random.uniform(0.00000000000000, 0.0001))                #sigma0
    b = str(random.uniform(0.00000000000000, 1))                     #sigmaslope
    c = str(random.uniform(0.05000000000000, 0.1))                   #viscosity
    d = str(random.uniform(0.00000000000000, 0.00001))                #aspectratio

    f = open('a.par','r')
    filedata = f.read()
    f.close()

    newdata = filedata.replace("6.3661977237e-4", a)
    newdata = filedata.replace("0.0", b)
    newdata = filedata.replace("0.05", c)
    newdata = filedata.replace("1e-5", d)

    f = open('a.par','w')
    f.write(newdata) 
    f.close()
```

Comment: ignore the for i in range line.

Comment: add 2 lines between each of the `newdata = ...` lines. `print(newdata)`, `print(filedata)`

Comment: @fdsa this still only replaces one line.

Comment: But look at what it's printing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug is in the section:

```
newdata = filedata.replace("6.3661977237e-4", a)
newdata = filedata.replace("0.0", b)
newdata = filedata.replace("0.05", c)
newdata = filedata.replace("1e-5", d)
```

Last line will always overwrite the `newdata` with `filedata`. So, all previous `filedata.replace()` will be of no use.

You can fix it by replacing `filedata` by `newdata`:

```
newdata = filedata.replace("6.3661977237e-4", a)
newdata = newdata.replace("0.0", b)
newdata = newdata.replace("0.05", c)
newdata = newdata.replace("1e-5", d)
```

Let me know if this doesnt fix your issue.

Comment: sort of new to this, apologies, but consider it done!